# How can I get independant without retrieving from a specific url my public ipv4 address?

Tags: python-2.7, sockets, networking

So, I am writing a program which requires a server and a client.
While writing it I want to attach the program to the 'public' IPV4 address which for some reason is also not mentioned in the CMD after searching quite some time.

I found tons of websites of going to: https://whatsmyip.com/ and retrieving from there by urlib or urlib2 and many other techniques but they require using a made already website.

I want this to be independant, not that I think that 'https://whatsmyip.com/' is going to change any time soon.. But I want my program to have no connection to other websites. I want to get it 'on my own'.
It might be a duplicate but I found so many duplicates regarding this and all I've seen is to enter and grab from the website.

I tried socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
It receives me the private ipv4 address.
Not the same address that whatsmyip.com gives me.

Comment: You are seeing one of the ugly sides of NAT. IP was designed to be end-to-end, and NAT breaks that. IP has no distinction between public and private addressing, and a host has no idea if its packets get translated. You need something receiving the packets on the other side of a translation to tell you what the translation is.

Comment: But what if I open a server on myself?

Comment: The detection of the translation must happen _after_ the translation. Your own host has no idea if translation is happening, or not.

Comment: But in case I open a server on a different router I am able to get it right?

Comment: If I understand what you are proposing, that is really the same thing the servers you do not want to use do. They simply look at the source address on the packets they receive to see shat the public address is.

Comment: I understood you, but as you say I must have any translation inorder to know my IPV4 since its something regardless my computer. Tl;Dr I have to use networking inorder to know my ipv4 address. Without using an external server like whatsmyip.com can I contact the translator directly in some way inorder to ask for the ipv4 address?

Comment: Your host has no way to know if NAT is even being performed, or where.